# Setting age restriction returns false

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restrictions

Using the sample PHP code on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574) works great for setting the restriction to `{"location":"US"}` however it returns false when trying to set it to `{"age":18}` or `{"age":"18"}`. Is there a special way which this needs to be formatted in order to set an age restriction?

See the list of available restrictions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `{"age":"18"}`, use `{"age_distribution":"18+"}`.

I don't know why using "age" doesn't work.  The documentation says it should work, but it didn't work for me either.

However, using `age_distribution` does work.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
{"type":"alcohol"}
```

this should only be a workaround as the legal age for alcohol is similar